# Unable to boot to Ubuntu

Tags: installation, boot, boot-repair, grub-efi

Just got a new laptop and removed Windows 8 and installed 13.10 using LiveUSB. Initially it was booting to "No boot media" but I was able to resolve it with boot-repair. I realized some of the items I need isn't supported on 13.10, so attempted to install 13.04 instead.

Now without LiveUSB, the laptop just boots to "No boot media" but boot repair doesn't seem to be fixing it. Tried going back to 13.10, but no dice. 
After boot repair it says "Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sda1/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi file!". GParted shows sda1 has the boot flag.

Using Toshiba Satellite P50. Secure Boot disabled. UEFI enabled. 
Any help would be highly appreciated.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/6366556/

Comment: Got it working. Noticed that the following boot files were missing from the efi partition (sda1) between the working case and non-working case.

 - /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi 
 - /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
 - /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootx64.efi

Running boot repair again and selecting the following options fixed the issue:

-Backup and Rename EFI files (solves the [hard-coded-EFI] error)
-Use standard EFI File

Before: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6366556/
After:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/6367391/

Comment: You might consider to post this as an answer to your own question (which is absolutely in the spirit of this site).

Comment: I tried. Didn't have enough rep to answer my own question within 2 hours of posting :)

Answer (score 3):

Got it working. 
Noticed that the following boot files were missing from the efi partition (sda1) between the working case and non-working case.

- /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
- /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
- /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootx64.efi

Running boot repair again and selecting the following options fixed the issue:

- Backup and Rename EFI files (solves the [hard-coded-EFI] error)
- Use standard EFI File